# ASP.NET Webform shows Error.ASPX page on runtime Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm just guessing this is a simple ASP.NET question :)

So here it is:

I have ASP.NET solution and everytime a "Runtime" Error happens a web page called Error.ASPX is shown.(call stack shows source as none-user code!)

I searched all of the code(including web.config) for any reference to "Error.ASPX" but could not find it.

So flow does not go to the Error.ASPX from the code itself. My guess is this is somewhere specified in the Visual Studio settings.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: have you checked the global file `Application_Error` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many place in you project where it may have written.

1. Global.asax  `Application_Error` event.
2. pageName.aspx `Page_Error` event.

Or you may have created a class inherited from `Page` class where `Page_Error` may have written and you are using that class rather than page class.
There are may possibilities for your question.

Comment: But as I said above I do a search for Error.aspx but cant find in any file.

Comment: Yes it was in global.ASax and in Application_Error.
Response.Redirect("~/shared/error.aspx")

 Sadly this wasted 1 hour of my time simply because VS2003 Search DOES NOT work correctly.

Even though I specify "All open documents" and also check "Search hidden text". VS search does not find the error.aspx inside the global.asax

Answer (score 2):

You could be overriding a setting in the Global.asax file but I would just handle it in the  section of the web.config (in `<system.web>`). By default, you should already have the section commented out as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

The mode="RemoteOnly" will only show custom error pages when the request doesn't come from the localhost so you can still see details from the server.